# Oracle Group Subset of Selection Columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column called vs_tblRentals which has the following columns:

```
RENTALID    CUSTOMERID    BOXID    RENTALDATE       RETURNDATE
```

As well as a column called vs_tblBoxes which has the following columns

```
BOXID       MOVIEID       MEDIUMTYPECODE       DATEBOXRECEIVED
```

I am trying to create a query that retrieve how many times each value in the BoxID column of vs_tblBoxes appears in the BoxID column of vs_tblRentals, essentially telling me how many times each box has been rented. I can do this through the following command:

```
SELECT COUNT(vs_tblRentals.BoxID) AS RentalCount
FROM vs_tblRentals
LEFT JOIN vs_tblBoxes B ON vs_tblRentals.BoxID = B.BoxID
GROUP BY vs_tblRentals.BoxID;
```

However, I also want to display information along side this RentalCount that is NOT part of the group- ideally my output would look something like this:

```
BoxID    MovieID   MediumTypeCode   RentalCount
```

I would also like to display all the records in vs_tblRentals for the Boxes that have been rented more than 5 times.

How is this supposed to be done in Oracle 12c?

EDIT:

The following code successfully gets the Rental Count for each BoxID:

```
SELECT COUNT(vs_tblRentals.BoxID) AS RentalCount, vs_tblRentals.BoxID
FROM vs_tblRentals
LEFT JOIN vs_tblBoxes B ON vs_tblRentals.BoxID = B.BoxID
GROUP BY vs_tblRentals.BoxID;
```

And outputs the following:

```
RENTALCOUNT BOXID
1           337
1           691
1           43
4           321
4           123
4           665
4           674
```

But I cannot get this to work while displaying other information about the BoxID alongside this.

Sample Data From vs_tblBoxes:

```
BOXID   MOVIEID  MEDIUMTYPECODE     DATEBOXRECEIVED 
257     702      BD                 22-Nov-1953 
258     708      VHS                16-Jul-1988 
259     708      DVD                16-Jul-1988
```

Sample data from vs_tblRentals

```
RENTALID    CUSTOMERID  BOXID   RENTALDATE    RETURNDATE    
1           1           257     06-Apr-2018   22-Apr-2018   
2           1           257     22-Mar-2018   NULL
3           1           259     26-Feb-2018   16-Mar-2018
```

Comment: can you share sample data and output?

Comment: What would you like to see? I've updated the OP with the output of the code I originally included (with a slight modification).

Comment: Provide the data in your tables from which this output originates..

Comment: Please [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). it isn't of great interest to see the output of a query that does not meet your requirements. What would be useful is **sample data** and **the expected result** (as text tables not images)

Comment: What's the relation between your sample data and expected result?

Comment: I'd expect BoxID 257 to have a Rental Count of 2, BoxID 258 to have a Rental Count of 0, and Box ID 259 to have a Rental Count of 1. I'd then want to display other information about the Box identified by BoxID next to the Rental Count, such as MovieID.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is probably to left join the tables in the opposite order (make entries in vs_tblRentals optional instead of the other way around), add the extra columns to the select and `GROUP BY` them too.

```
SELECT B.BoxID, B.MovieID, B.DateBoxReceived, COUNT(R.BoxID) AS RentalCount
FROM vs_tblBoxes B 
LEFT JOIN vs_tblRentals R
  ON R.BoxID = B.BoxID
GROUP BY B.BoxID, B.MovieID, B.DateBoxReceived;
```

Using `GROUP BY` on Oracle (in contrast to for example MySQL) requires you specify your query more fully and either group on each column you want to extract or generate it using an aggregate function (such as `MAX`or `COUNT`)

Doing neither will render an error.

Comment: When I perform a GROUP BY on the additional columns, the functionality I am aiming for- that is, getting the number of times the BoxID appears in the rental table, breaks. Because I'm grouping by all the columns, the count returns a value of 1 for each row. I assume this is because when all the columns are grouped each rows exact configuration is unique.

Comment: This is why we need to see **sample data** and the **expected result**, currently the only one able to "see" both is @RJGordon

Comment: @RJGordon I can't see that happening with your sample data (example in PostgreSQL since SqlFiddle w/ Oracle seems tired at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n7ENz2XdURmeUuB5f9bsyy/0 where the count seems correct)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of left join use right outer join to do so..

```
select b.boxId, count(*) as RentalCount from 
vs_tblRentals r right outer join vs_tblBoxes b
on b.boxId = r.boxId group by b.boxId;
```